# How to fill columns of a matrix with random numbers of specific range?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've a matrix of order `100*10` . Now the objective is to fill each columns of the matrix with random integer within a specific range. Now the problem is for every column the range of the random number changes. For instance, for the first column, the range is `[1,100]` , for the second its `-10 to 1` and so on till 10th column.

This is what I've tried:

```
b = [0,100;-10,1;0,1;-1,1;10,20]
a = []
for i=1 to 10
    a[] = [(i:100)' randi(1,100)]
end
```

How do I generate a matrix of this form?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have matlab installed right now, but i would do something like this.

```
m = 100;
n = size(b, 1);
range  = b(:, 2) - b(:, 1);
offset = b(:, 1);

A = round(bsxfun(@minus, bsxfun(@times, rand(m, n), range), offset);
```

Without loop it would become:

```
M = 100;
N = size(b, 1);

A = zeros(m, n); % preallocate to avoid matrix expansion
for ii = 1:n
    A(:, ii) = randi(b(ii,:), m, 1);
end
```

Comment: Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree this is what i get

Comment: For multiplying the matrix and vector, I suppose you would need to use `bsxfun`

Comment: An edit to this answer or a separate answer would be much helpful!