# How to fill columns of a matrix with random numbers of specific range of a 100*5 matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've a matrix of order `100*5` . Now the objective is to fill each columns of the matrix with random integer within a specific range. Now the problem is for every column the range of the random number changes. For instance, for the first column, the range is 1 to 100 , for the second its -10 to 1 and so on till 5th column.

This is what I've tried:

```
b = [0,100;-10,1;0,1;-1,1;10,20]
range = b(:,2) - b(:,1) 
offset = b(:,1)
A = round(rand(100,5) * range - offset)
```

which is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586752/how-to-fill-columns-of-a-matrix-with-random-numbers-of-specific-range) question.  However this generates an error,

> Error using  *  Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

What's possibly causing this and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Avoid using `range` as a variable name, as it's a [function name](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/range.html?s_tid=doc_ta)

Comment: @EBH Even after changing the var name, the same error persis

Comment: This is not the cause for the error, just a good habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lets `bsxfun` this thing!

```
A = round(bsxfun(@minus,bsxfun(@times,rand(100,5) ,range'), offset'))
```

Comment: @OBX Seems like you got an answer from a real wizard!

Comment: BTW, I think `randi` is faster, but I'm not sure it's simpler to implement it with it.

Comment: @EBH yeah probably, just left is as it is as I assumed that the problem may be more complicated than this

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution, you could use `repmat` to complete what you already had:

```
b = [0, 100; -10, 1; 0, 1; -1, 1; 10, 20].'; 
rng = b(2, :) - b(1, :); 
ofst = b(1, :);
A = round(rand(100,5) .* repmat(rng, 100, 1) + repmat(ofst, 100, 1));
```

You don't have to define `rng` or `ofst`, and this can be simply written as:

```
A = round(rand(10,5) .* repmat(diff(b), 10, 1) + repmat(b(1,:), 10, 1));
```

---

Out of curiousity I wrote this quick benchmark* to compare to Ander's `bsxfun` method. It appears that `bsxfun` has some initial overhead which means for 5 columns (test other cases yourself) and less than a few thousand rows, `repmat` is quicker. Above this, the creation of additional large arrays by `repmat` probably causes a slow down, and we see `bsxfun` is much quicker.

[image: small vals]
[image: large vals]

For future readers if this doesn't apply to you: **with [broadcasting introduced from R2016b](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) you may find you can dodge using `bsxfun` and `repmat` entirely.**

*benchmarking code. Tested on Windows 64-bit R2015b, your mileage may vary etc.

```
function benchie()
    b = [0, 100; -10, 1; 0, 1; -1, 1; 10, 20].';
    Tb = [];
    Tr = [];
    K = 20;
    for k = 1:K
        n = 2^k;
        fb = @()bsxfunMethod(b,n);
        fr = @()repmatMethod(b,n);
        Tb(end+1) = timeit(fb);
        Tr(end+1) = timeit(fr);
    end
    figure; plot(2.^(1:K), Tb, 2.^(1:K), Tr); legend('bsxfun', 'repmat');
end
function bsxfunMethod(b, n)
    round(bsxfun(@minus,bsxfun(@times, rand(n,5), diff(b)), b(1,:)));
end
function repmatMethod(b, n)
    round(rand(n,5) .* repmat(diff(b), n, 1) + repmat(b(1,:), n, 1));
end
```

Comment: The result that `repmat` is quicker than `bsxfun` is [somewhat surprising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat).

Comment: Thanks for the link, can you replicate my results on your own machine? I feel like the benchmark above is reasonable, but of course subtle differences to the use cases in that question may affect things! As I speculate, there may be some initial `bsxfun` overhead since it is much quicker for large arrays

Comment: When I run this for the range 1-10000 rows, I get a [noisy pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ym9.png), with a general advantage for `repmat`. When I run it for 2-2^20 range, I get the same result as yours.

Comment: Hmm I wonder where that noise comes from, are you using a version with the newer JIT compiler?

Comment: I use MATLAB 2017a.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`randi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html), passing in rows of `b` to its first argument:

```
b = [0,100;-10,1;0,1;-1,1;10,20];
A = zeros(100,5);
f=@(ii)randi(b(ii,:),100,1);
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
  A(:,ii) = f(ii);
end
```

I suspect there is a way of doing this without looping through rows/columns, probably with [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

Comment: @OBX See edit. Probably, but I'm not enough of a MATLAB wizard

Comment: Ah! Matlab wizars are needed! :P Happy to find you here!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`arrayfun`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), even though I don't see any harm in using loops and writing more readable code as in Steve's answer.

```
A = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(imin, imax) randi([imin, imax], 100, 1), b(:,1), b(:,2), 'uni', 0)')
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, `arrayfun` **is** a loop (inside).

Comment: And it's slower than a simple `for`.